# Laravel 9: run project without using php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I want to run my laravel 9 app without 'php artisan serve'
i know how to do it in older version but laravel 9 don't have the server.php file in root directory
so how to do it now

and i don't want to use 'localhost/project/public/' url

I am currently on
laravel: version 9.19
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
php: 8.1.2
Server: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you using XAMPP? There are multiple ways to run a Laravel locally. Valet, docker, the serve command, ...  or add an .htaccess file to rewrite to /public . The server.php file is relocated and is used for the artisan serve command...

Comment: yes i am using xampp, tell me the steps or any article link, i have searched a lot for this but did not get a single article about this

Comment: XAMMP is not the best option for Laravel development

Comment: @GertB. Not really XAMPP but LAMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to add your project to list of virtual hosts in XAMPP that is located in \apache\conf\extra > httpd-vhosts.conf

It can be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "{pathToProject}\public"
    ServerName projectname.localhost
    <Directory "{pathToProject}">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Second step is to add host in your hosts file that is located in same disk as your OS then \Windows\System32\drivers\etc > hosts
It should probably be something like
127.0.0.1       projectname.localhost

If you've changed default address settings, you will have to change address in hosts as well.

Restart XAMPP and you're good to go.

Comment: hey, sorry for my incomplete question, i have edited my question, i forgot to mention that i am using linux and i think you solution is for windows